# Is there a way to force Yii2 to reload module assets on every request?

Tags: php, yii, assets, yii2

My website is divided into separate modules. Every module has it's own specific css or js files.
Yii's assetManager creates a folder when I first open a page that uses my assets.

Unfortunately if I change something in my files Yii 1.x does not reload my css or js files.

I have to manually delete the web/assets folder. It is really annoying when you are developing the app.

This works when I add a module to the backend folder, but not when I'm creating a module in the vendor folder with my own namespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With respect to Yii1.x With `assetManager` you can do this by setting 'forceCopy' attribute to true in your config file

> ... copy the asset files and directories even if they already published
>   before. This property is used only during development stage

See forceCopy documentation [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CAssetManager#forceCopy-detail) for more info.

Alternatively you can use `linkAssets` which will not copy the files but create an soft link between your asset files and yours assets directory. You cannot of course use both.

For the second part of the question I am assuming this is in Yii 2.x, you are supposed to use AssetBundles, you can register any namespace bundle from anywhere, you simply register it in the view with some like this

```
use vendor\myVendorName\myPackageName\assets\AppAsset;
AppAsset::register($this);
```

Comment: do you have an example for the linkAssets?

Comment: I added this line in the components of the main config: 'assetManager' => ['linkAssets' => true,], thanks

Answer (score 2):

In Yii2 you can append a timestamp to the URLs of assets like this...

```
return [
    // ...
    'components' => [
        'assetManager' => [
            'appendTimestamp' => true,
        ],
    ],
];
```

This won't force the assets to reload on every request but whenever an asset file is changed the URL will change because of the timestamp & that will force the asset to be re-published.

Comment: also see my comment on Manquer's answer

Comment: This approach is recommended in the Yii2 docs & causes the browser to reload the changed asset because of the changed URL. A changed file at the end of a link might be not reloaded by the browser. I personally avoid using links because they aren't always allowed on the hosts I deploy to.

Comment: @Pedro is there any typo in your code snippet? I used it in `common/config/main.php` but it causes an error about `Setting unknown property: yii\web\AssetManager::appendTimestamp`?

Comment: That snippet was copied directly from the Yii2 docs... http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-assets.html#cache-busting

Answer (score 2):

You can set `forceCopy = true`.

```
class Assets extends AssetBundle{

    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();
        $this->publishOptions['forceCopy'] = true;
    }
}
```